# backtick vs system in ruby

Tags: ruby

Base on all my readings on the web the difference between `backtick` and `system` is what is returned . `backtick` returns STDOUT while `system` returns `true` or `false`.

And I was told that both of them use subshell to perform the operation.

However I am noticing another difference.

```
output = system('aaa')
puts "output is: #{output}"

output = `aaa`
puts "output is: #{output}"
```

Result of above code is

```
$ ruby test.rb
output is: 
lab.rb:4:in ``': No such file or directory - aaa (Errno::ENOENT) from test.rb:4:in `<main>'
```

So it seems in the case of `backtick` the exceptions are raised to the main program. Operation `system` swallows the exception and the main program never sees the exception.

I'm using ruby 1.9.3 .

Is my analysis right ?

UPDATE: Got the answer. It's here https://gist.github.com/3730986 .

Comment: Take a look at [5 ways to run commands from Ruby](http://mentalized.net/journal/2010/03/08/5_ways_to_run_commands_from_ruby/); explains the specifics of each of ways to run a unix command from ruby.

Comment: @PrakashMurthy I looked at before asking the question. That article does not say anything about exceptions are raise to the main program or not. Thank you.

Comment: [Executing Commands in Ruby](http://blog.bigbinary.com/2012/10/18/backtick-system-exec-in-ruby.html) is a nice article which does talk about the exception handling.

Comment: @nodejs99 you can answer your own question (then it will not appear as unanswered forever)

Comment: @nodejs99 - If you're game to recap the solution as your own answer, I'll delete my answer. (See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90263/unanswered-question-answered-in-comments for elaboration of why this is helpful.) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Copying the answer from the edited question body in order to remove this question from the "Unanswered" filter:

> Got the answer. It's here https://gist.github.com/3730986 .

~ answer per [nodejs99](https://stackoverflow.com/users/447989/nodejs99)